# Asymptotic Distribution of Order Statistic for a uniform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution, probability-limit-theorems, order-statistics

I am trying to find the asymptotic distribution of an order statistic $X_{(n)}$ for  iid RVs $X_1, ..., X_n \sim \mathrm{Unif}(0,a)$, where $a>0$.

The distribution for $X_{(n)}$

$$f(X_{(n)}=x) = \frac{nx^{n-1}}{a^n}I(0<x<a)$$

My gut reaction was to find the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ of the CDF, and see if this resembled another distribution.  This gave me

$$\frac{x^n}{a^n}$$

My guess is there is a trick or a property I am forgetting.  Note: the actual problem was more involved, I simplified it to just include the component I unsure about.

Comment: You seem to be using $n$ both as the total number of variables, and as the order statistic.  Are you saying you want to find the asymptotic distribution of the _last_ order statistic?  As $n \to \infty$?  Wouldn't it basically $\to a$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Z_n = n(X_{(n)}/a-1).$ Then $$ P(Z_n\le z) = P(X_{(n)}/a\le 1+z/n) =(1+z/n)^n\sim e^z.$$ So the distribution is asymoptitically reverse-exponential.

Comment: In other words, $n(1-X_{(n)}/a)$ converges in distribution to the standard exponential. An weaker statement will be that $X_{(n)}$ converges in probability to $a$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! I just would never think to do this.  What was your intuition for this?  How did you know to go in this direction?

Comment: @kpr62 First $a$'s not an issue since it's just a scale so always just divide $X_(n)$ by it. Second thought about the distribution is going to cluster near 1 and how $x^n$ looks, it gets closer and closer to a step function, so we're going to need to rescale by some function of $n.$ (Third, I've done many of these kinds of problems, somewhat of a long time ago, but I have some feel for them still.)

Comment: @kpr62 Incidentally, there is kind of a template theorem for all of these (sort of how there is a general template for showing statistics are asymptotically normal) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem (this one is Weibull family if i recall correctly). I've never liked or really understood the technical way in which it's usually presented, when it's really just a a few tricks to turn things into exponential limits like in this problem.